# manter a quantidade apos refresh

Tags: php

Assim eu adiciono o produto:

```
 if (isset($_GET['acao'])) {
    if ($_GET['acao'] == 'add') {
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
  if (!empty($_SESSION['shop'][$id]))
    //if (!isset($_SESSION['shop'][$id]))
        $_SESSION['shop'][$id] = 1;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['shop'][$id] += 1;
    }  e aqui o input :   echo'<td><input rel="'.$linha['id'].'" type="number" step="1" min="1" style="width:50px; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 20px;" name="prod[' . $id . ']" value="' . $qtd . '"></td>';
```

Gostaria de saber como posso manter a quantidade após um refresh.
Por exemplo: se escolho 2 produtos, ao atualizar a página, volta a quantidade de 1 produto.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas simples erro de lógica

Sugestão de correção

```
 if (
     isset($_GET['acao'])
     && $_GET['acao'] == 'add'
 ) {
     $id = intval($_GET['id']);
     if (
         isset($_SESSION['shop'][$id])
         || empty($_SESSION['shop'][$id])
     ) {
         $_SESSION['shop'][$id] = 1;
     } else {
         $_SESSION['shop'][$id] += 1;
     }
 }
```

Nota: Esteja ciente de que num refresh/reload da página, os valores serão constantemente incrementados.